# Flutter-Firebase Reference Path Does Not Work Correctly

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listtile

I want to get QR/Code Outputs data for title in Listtile and QRCode/Total Number for subtitle.

My code is below. I think everything seem good and have no idea why it doesn't work correctly.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JDTA.png)

Can anyone help me with this ?

```
class ScannedBarcode extends StatelessWidget {
  //const ScannedBarcode({super.key});

  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("QR Code");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("QR/Barcode Data"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent[100],
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: ref,
                defaultChild: Text('Loading'),
                itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: 3),
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 25.0),
                    tileColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                        snapshot.child("QR Code/Outputs").value.toString()),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot
                        .child("QR Code/Total Number")
                        .value
                        .toString()),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `FirebaseAnimatedList` is used to show lists of data, but I don't see a list of values under the `FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("QR Code")` in your database. There are just two properties there with known names, so I don't think an `FirebaseAnimatedList` is the correct widget to use for that. Did you consider using a `StreamBuilder` for loading the data, and `Text` widgets for displaying it?

Comment: I got  this error "type null is not a subtype of type Map<dynamic,dynamic>" with streambuilder